# UITableView Scrolling time face the issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uiview

I create a UITableView and then after I give a shadow to the table view. But when I apply the shadow to the table view at that time scrolling effect has some issues and does not give proper scrolling effect.

Here is the shadow code:

```
extension UIView {
    func shadow() {
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: -1)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
}
```

And my TableViewControl.swift file's viewDidLoad() code is:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.shadow() //If I comment this line, so output became Proper
}
```

The error looks like this (tableView scrolling goes outside the tableView area):

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: try with self.layer.masksToBounds = true

Comment: @NiravS `self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES` add this inside your section

Comment: Ya I already put this line into code, But using this line my whole view became blur.. So I removed this line..

Comment: Ok. have you tried adding shadowPath `self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath` like this? .It usually increases performance

Comment: `self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath` add this in your shadow method(extension)

Comment: @Aditya I add this line but It's not working. I think in this issue only one first top cell goes outside the tableview area..

Comment: what is the problem after adding this line?

Comment: same issue which I already face. Some Lighter shadow is appear on top of the tableView and whose size is same as first top cell.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = true
self.layer.clipToBounds = true
```

OR

[image]

check the clip To Bounds of UITableView.

pls try this.

Comment: If I add ->tableView.clipsToBounds = true line so shadow effect goes, and I also try to set ->tableView.layer.masksToBounds = true so also shadow is goes.

Comment: And In story board my options are same as per your given snap

Comment: so that pls check the constraints of UITableView

Comment: But when I remove the shadow effect so it's working properly. So I think it's not about constraints.

Comment: tableView.shadow() implement this method in cell class not in VC.

Comment: I add this line into cell so cell have shadow effect but my problem is as it is..

Comment: can you give me one fever. In this gif you can observe that between cell line is appear but it's not in full width, It's cut from left side. Can you give  me any suggestion ? Please..

Comment: it is seperator

Comment: ya I know but I also have this is issue. (I tried to solve this issue using CALayer but not achieve desired output of border line)

Comment: tableView.separatorStyle = .none

Comment: Separator width size is perfect from right side but not in left side. Few margin is visible

Comment: check in storyBoard -> Seperator insets ->change it to custom

Comment: Have u  give shadow to table or cell ?

Comment: I give shadow to table view. Because I need not give shadow to cell

Comment: Ur tableView inside a view or not ?

Comment: Put UitableView inside a UIView and check the clipToBounds of UIView. May be it helps you

Comment: Its Work @NiravS

Comment: Ya.. Dutt tell me this same thing and he is correct. Thanks Arun to give me suggestion related my issue.

Comment: Ohh.. ok ok.. Thats why I give you Upward my Bro.. Thanks.

Comment: Thnx a lot bro.

Answer (score 0):

do the following:

In Storyboard, Add a Tableview in separate view.

[image: In Storyboard, Add a Tableview in separate view.]

[image]

change this code in your code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.superview?.shadow()    // instead of this tableView.shadow()
}
```

Comment: Yaa.. It's working but now I nee check touches and all related things. Till now we achieve desired out put. So thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternate solution for this ..

Take a UIView (let's say containerView ) from storyboard and make its top, bottom, leading, trailing margins equal to your tableView

and instead of giving shadow to tableView , add shadow to containerView

containerView.shadow()

Note :  Your tableView needs to be above containerView to make this code run
Hope this will help!!